# Map a result of an SQL to a field using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am looking for a way of mapping an SQL result of type bool to a field of an entity.

Here's the code I need to work with:

```java
    @Formula("next_erds_id is null \n" +
            "and exists(\n" +
            "    select * from processes p\n" +
            "    where p.message_uuid = message_uuid \n" +
            "        and exists(select * from process_tasks t\n" +
            "            where t.process_uuid = p.process_uuid and t.task_name = 'MP_MESSAGE_PROCESSED')\n" +
            "        and not exists(select * from process_tasks t\n" +
            "            where t.process_uuid = p.process_uuid and t.task_name = 'CH_NOTIFICATION_CREATED') \n" +
            ")")
    private boolean canNotifyOnStartDeliveryAfter;
```

(Please ignore the field name. I've got no idea what it is supposed to mean...)

Of course, it does not work because it's not a valid MSSQL syntax.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: hibernate formula run as a subquery , your formula is not a subquery !!

Comment: @MohammadMirzaeyan I know that. Unfortunately, my colleague does not. Is there a quick way I can make it work on MSSQL?

Comment: fix it and make it as a subquery or if you can't do that use a hql query that does not select the formula field , i dont understand what you mean about the quick way !!!